# Where'd the Icon for Show Snippet go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-snippets

I've recently noticed that SO looks slightly differently today (yay! I love change).

However, after answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981215/strange-offset-on-images-displayed-inline-block/27981408?noredirect=1#comment44354890_27981408), which includes a code snippet, I can't seem to see the caret icon next to the 'show snippet' option:

[image]

This is the same of 'hide snippet'

Although that area is still clickable. Is this a change that has been made on purpose? Or does it work, just not on my machine?

Comment: The icon was removed in the new design probably, I don't see it either.

Comment: Is this status-completed as of the next build, @Haney?

Comment: @hichris123 it will be completed when indicated in the dupe. ;)